# Error handling in Dart with throw catch. (Catch doesn't seem to execute)

Tags: dart, dartium

I'm trying out Dart for the first time and I can't get the error handling to work for me. Here's some information about it.

**Resources:**

- Gist with HTML, CSS and Dart: [gist.github.com/enjikaka/8164610](https://gist.github.com/enjikaka/8164610)
- ZIP with the project: [ge.tt/6StW4cB1/v/0?c](http://ge.tt/6StW4cB1/v/0?c)
- JavaScript version on CodePen: [codepen.io/enjikaka/pen/giurk](http://codepen.io/enjikaka/pen/giurk)

**How I want it:**

Making an instance of MinecraftSkin should throw an StateError if the image source returns a 403 error code. The exception should be handled in the generateHead() function where the instance of MineCraft skin is attempted to be made.

**How it is:**

If an image representing the skin of a MineCraft player does not exist (when the image source does not exist and returns 403) the code stops on line 22 (onError; where I throw the StateError) and prints to console "Breaking on exception: Bad state: User has no skin".

However, in the catch on generateHead, nothing gets executed. It doesn't print the StateError message when I prompt it to, neither does it insert the StateError message to the selected element in the DOM.

**Code**

```dart
import 'dart:html';

class MinecraftSkin {
    String user;
    CanvasElement ce = new CanvasElement();

    void _generateCanvas(Event e) {
        CanvasRenderingContext2D ctx = ce.getContext('2d');
        ctx.imageSmoothingEnabled = false;
        ctx.drawImageScaledFromSource((e.target as ImageElement),8,8,8,8,0,0,ce.width,ce.height);
    }

    CanvasImageSource getHead() => ce;
    String name() => user;

    MinecraftSkin(String minecraftUser, num size) {
        user = (minecraftUser == null) ? 'Notch' : minecraftUser;
        ce.width = size;
        ce.height = size;
        ImageElement img = new ImageElement()
            ..onLoad.listen(_generateCanvas)
            ..onError.listen((_) => throw new StateError('User has no skin'));
        img.src = "http://s3.amazonaws.com/MinecraftSkins/"+user+".png";
    }
}

void generateHead(Event e) {
    MinecraftSkin ms;
    try {
        ms = new MinecraftSkin((querySelector('#userName') as InputElement).value, 128);
    } on StateError catch(se) {
        print(se.message);
        querySelector('#status').text = se.message;
    }
    CanvasElement cems = ms.getHead();
    cems.id = "mc" + ms.name();
    cems.title = "mc" + ms.name();
    document.body.append(cems);
    querySelector('#status').text = "Got head!";
}

void main() {
    querySelector('#generateHead').onClick.listen(generateHead);
}
```

Thanks in advance!

*Sincerely, Jeremy*

Answer (score 1):

The image listeners (onLoad, onError) are asynchronous. The MincraftSkin instantiation is completed without any errors, and only after the image resource is loaded or an error is received, is the StateError thrown, probably several hundred milliseconds later. The constructor does not wait around to see if the image will properly load or not.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But how would I go about fixing this? Using a HttpRequest to check before loading image? Or should I throw the StateError somewhere else in the MinecraftSkin class? If this a case where I should use Futures?

Comment: I'm not really sure what the best practice is here, which is why I didn't suggest any alternatives in my answer. I think Futures are definitely needed here, perhaps as a factory that returns a Future<MinecraftSkin>. Using an extra HttpRequest doesn't seem great, due to the increased response time and wasted bandwidth.

Comment: Ok! I have encountered Futures before, and didn't get the hang of it. I guess it's time to dive deep into that Futures and Error Handling article. If anyone could provide an example that'd be great!